# Expand canvas/transparent background in BitmapImage in a WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

This is a follow up question on [Save image to file keeping aspect ration in a WPF app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648456/save-image-to-file-keeping-aspect-ratio-in-a-wpf-app)

I know howto scale the image, but how do I expand the canvas size, to ensure the image still has the requested width and height. In this example its 250x250 but its dynamic.

I have created this illustration to show what I'm trying to accomplice.
[image]

I can't find any way of expanding the canvas of an BitmapImage, nor a way to create an in  memory image in the correct size, with a transparent background, and then merging the two images together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CroppedBitmap doesn't seem to support adding space around an image so instead you can create a transparent image the correct size using [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx). If the input is smaller than the target size this method will enlarge it, but that is easy to alter.

```
public static BitmapSource FitImage(BitmapSource input, int width, int height)
{
    if (input.PixelWidth == width && input.PixelHeight == height)
        return input;

    if(input.Format != PixelFormats.Bgra32 || input.Format != PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
        input = new FormatConvertedBitmap(input, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 0);

    //Use the same scale for x and y to keep aspect ratio.
    double scale = Math.Min((double)width / input.PixelWidth, height / (double)input.PixelHeight);

    int x = (int)Math.Round((width - (input.PixelWidth * scale))/2);
    int y = (int)Math.Round((height - (input.PixelHeight * scale))/2);


    var scaled = new TransformedBitmap(input, new ScaleTransform(scale, scale));
    var stride = scaled.PixelWidth * (scaled.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);

    var result = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, input.DpiX, input.DpiY, input.Format,null);

    var data = new byte[scaled.PixelHeight * stride];
    scaled.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);
    result.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0,0,scaled.PixelWidth,scaled.PixelHeight), data, stride,x,y);
    return result;
}
```

If you are already rendering content using RenderTargetBitmap you could wrap it in a ViewBox to do the scaling but if you're just working with normal images I'd use the above method.

Comment: @Kris This sounds very promising. I'm new to these methods. Can you tell me the difference between BitmapSource and BitmapFrame? I am using BitmapFrame to resize my image.

Comment: @Kris Okay I see that BitmapFrame is child of BitmapSource. So should be able to adapt code to work. Trying myself right now.

Comment: The main use for BitmapFrame is because some image formats like gif can have multiple frames it also ties it to a decoder and provides a thumbnail, for a better explanation see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155391/difference-between-a-bitmapframe-and-bitmapimage-in-wpf

Comment: @Kris +50 Thank-you. Sorted it out. Your function is great and can be copied verbatim. I use was using PostedFile.InputStream converted to a BitmapFrame. Because BitmapFrame is a child of BitmapSource it is properly parsed, but the return object is a BitmapSource instead of BitmapFrame. To save this I had to convert it back to a BitmapFrame using BitmapFrame.Create(myBitmapSource). This seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: Edit- my initial comment was whacked. I was so excited about getting an answer. Your function is great and can be copied verbatim. In my case I was processing images from a form upload. This gave me myFile.PostedFile.InputStream which can be converted to a BitmapFrame by calling ReadBitmapFrame(myFile). This can then be passed directly into your function for processing. Unfortunately the output of your function is BitmapSource which I couldn't figure out how to save using encoder.Save. So I converted BitmapSource back into a frame using BitmapFrame.Create().

Comment: @mrtsherman I think BitmapFrame just wraps the source you provide and to save the image you will have to use BitmapFrame.Create. The latest edit only creates one WriteableBitmap instead of two.

Comment: @Kris - I ran into a small problem with this function. It seems that if the source file contains an area of transparency then I get a resized image with a transparent background. However, if I upload a jpg, bmp or png (no transparent pixels) the background is rendered black when saved. I tried specifying some color palettes, but no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kris - so after some plugging away I figured out what was wrong. I need to set the pixelformat of the uploaded file. Some png's do not have transparency enabled and obviously jpg and bmp never do. I used FormatConvertedBitmap fcb = new FormatConvertedBitmap(input, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 0); to convert the file before passing it on to your function.

Comment: The Output is created with the same format as the input the function should probably check if it supports alpha, I was just about to post an edit to the function that checks if and uses a FormatConvertedBitmap if not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605067%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property to Uniform.

Comment: How about saving the image from the canvas that it's on?

Comment: Any chance you could create a small example to illustrate this? As you can we in my previous question, I'm not using a canvas, but loads the image into a BitmapImage and then loads it into a TransformedBitmap to scale it down, but that just don't give the right output size.

Comment: You could try something like this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/908177f6-637d-4936-b4d6-3884d17ff7a7/

Answer (score 0):

Just some code in case others are trying to postprocess files from a form upload.

```
if (file.PostedFile != null)
{
    //write the new file to disk
    string cachePath = String.Format("{0}temp\\", Request.PhysicalApplicationPath);
    string photoPath = String.Format("{0}temp.png", cachePath);                
    if (!Directory.Exists(cachePath))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(cachePath);
}    

file.PostedFile.SaveAs(photoPath);

//resize the new file and save it to disk               
BitmapSource banana = FitImage(ReadBitmapFrame(file.PostedFile.InputStream), 640, 480);
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(banana));
FileStream pngStream = new FileStream(cachePath + "test.png", FileMode.Create);
encoder.Save(pngStream);
pngStream.Close();

//set a couple images on page to the newly uploaded and newly processed files
image.Src = "temp/temp.png";
image.Visible = true;
image2.Src = "temp/test.png"; 


   image2.Visible = true;
}
```